# HTML CSS - Stacking Divs Vertically

Tags: html, css, stack

I am trying to stack the links in the left-most column vertically.
I've tried several things but am having no luck.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/adRuz/112/

```
.box {
    background: #E8E8E8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px black;
    font-family: Georgia;
}

.col1 {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height: 500px;
}
.col2 {
    float:right;
    width: 70%;
    height:500px;
}

.orange-heading {
    color: #0000FF;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.title_link {
    font-size:20px;
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the `<br>` tag and it worked fine.

Also there was a mistake on the links where instead of `class` you had put `clas` so the desired font size was not set!

http://jsfiddle.net/eLC8C/

I hope I have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line:

```
.box a { display:block; }
```

One thing `display:block;` does is making the element start on a new line and stretching out as much as possible to left and right, thus creating the effect you wanted.

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/adRuz/113/)**

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to create a vertical menu. If yes you can try the sample code. It goes something like this

[Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/adRuz/115/)

Markup

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" clas="title_link">Section Title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" clas="title_link">Section Title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" clas="title_link">Section Title 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Css

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```